# Submit Form not Working in CodeIgniter 3.0.3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I was tasked to write a simple program in CodeIgniter.I am coding in Symfony 2 and I have no trouble creating forms for testing since Symfony 2 offers a nice CRUD through command line which CodeIgniter lacks.So i have to create manually everytime I am creating forms for testing..But in chrome, the form does nothing when submit button is hit, and in Mozilla, and error message something like

> The address wasn't understood
>
> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (localhost) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.
>
> You might need to install other software to open this address.

Controller

```
public function add_makers()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Add New Car Maker';
    $data['main_content'] = 'makers/add_makers';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nation_id', 'Nation_Id', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
        //echo "ok";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->makers_model->new_makers();
        //$this->load->view('makers/success');
    }
```

Form

```
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>


<?php echo form_open('makers/add_makers'); ?>

<label for="name">Name</label>
<?php
$data = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'name' => 'name'    
);
echo form_input($data);
?>

<label for="description">Description</label>
<?php
$data = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'name' => 'description'
);
echo form_textarea($data);
?>

<label for="nation_id">Country</label>

<?php 
$data = array(
    'name' => 'nation_id',
    'type' => 'text'
);
echo form_input($data);
?>
```

templates

```
<?php 
 /*
 *Load header contents, and footer
 *
 */
 $this->load->view('templates/header');
 $this->load->view($main_content);
 $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

I am running development in vagrant(ubuntu trusty) installed in Windows and I have no problem using this in Symfony2 or Laravel project.Rewrite is all enable by running

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Inside Apache, I configure virtual host this way

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  #ServerAdmin admin@yourdomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/
  #ServerName yourdomain.com
  #ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
 <Directory /var/www/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
 #ErrorLog /var/www/CodeIgniter-3.0.3/logs/httpd/yourdomain.com-error_log
 #CustomLog /var/log/httpd/yourdomain.com-access_log common
 </VirtualHost>
```

Out in the box, I have this .ht access pre configured inside

```
  Project
  /Application
   .htaccess


   <IfModule authz_core_module>
     Require all denied
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !authz_core_module>
     Deny from all
   </IfModule>
```

And lastly routes

```
 $route['makers/add_makers'] = 'makers/add_makers';
//$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
//$route['news'] = 'news';
//$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'services/index';
```

I already searched Google for this and  found no solution.Is there something missing in my files?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the html code generated by CI, and try to Enter the full post URL in the address bar, maybe something happen, and then check the log file of apache and php, may it be helpful to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

I modify the .htaccess and move it outside application folder and put in root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|styles|scripts|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1

#<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
#    mod_gzip_on       Yes
#    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
#    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
#    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
#    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
#    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
#    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
#    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
#</IfModule>
```

Refactor apache 2.4

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/Codeigniter
    AcceptPathInfo On
    <Directory /var/www/Codeigniter>
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Then inside config/config.php

```
 $config['base_url'] = '';//note the auto guessing.If I set this to localhost:8090/something, this form will not submitting


 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

I tried many solutions provided in google and other suggestions but none works.Just got it right by spending many hours in trying possible solutions.
I am using Vagrant and Ubuntu trusty in development.Previously , I used Wamp for this project and I have no problem submitting forms.